# How to set AMP Center Content Layout?

Tags: amp-html

I would like to know how to centers the content for amp page
like the ampbyexample [DEMO: HOUSING](https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/housing/preview/)?

I try to code as follow, but can't work!

```
<style amp-custom>
body{margin:0 auto; max-width: 985px; }
</style>
```

The max-width change to 985px, but the content at left side...
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create the wrapper div inside the body than apply the css rule

Please follow this

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <style amp-custom>    .wrapper{margin:0 auto; max-width: 985px; }</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Welcome to the mobile web</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you still looking for the solution?

Comment: YES, PLEASE!
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="zh">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample document</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="./regular-html-version.html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">

  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-accordion" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-accordion-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-install-serviceworker" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-install-serviceworker-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-fit-text" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-fit-text-0.1.js"></script>

    <style amp-custom>
body {margin:0 auto; max-width: 985px; width:100%; }
p {text-align: center;}


amp-accordion section[expanded] .show-more {display: none;}
amp-accordion section:not([expanded]) .show-less {display: none;}
.i-amphtml-accordion-header{cursor:pointer;background-color:#336699;padding-right:20px;border:1px solid #dfdfdf}
.nested-accordion h1 {font-size: 140px;background-color: #000;}
amp-accordion#hidden-header section[expanded] h1 {border: none;}

    </style>
```